# HTML for a centered equation with right-justified equation number

Tags: html, wordpress, math, equation

I need to write an equation in Wordpress, but this WP installation doesn't have the LaTeX plugin and any `<link>` or `<script>` tags I write get stripped. So what's the best way to write an equation with equation number `(23)`, for example?

```latex
                        P(x, y) = P(y|x)·P(x)           (23)
```

I was thinking something like this code:

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">P(x, y) = P(y|x)·P(x)</div>
<div style="text-align: right;">(23)</div>
```

The `(23)` would be on the next line instead of the same line... I could use float, but that seems potentially tricky. Is there a more semantic or natural way to do this in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.equation-cont {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="equation-cont">
   <span class="eq">P(x, y) = P(y|x)·P(x)</span>
   <span class="number-eq">(23)</span>
</div>
```

edited:

or you can simply do this, the important here is to wrap two span inside a div.

```css
.equation-cont {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.eq {
  margin-right: 20px
}
```

```html
<div class="equation-cont">
  <span class="eq">P(x, y) = P(y|x)·P(x)</span>
  <span class="number-eq">(23)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like a great answer. Unfortunately, looks like Wordpress strips out `display` properties. Though the other properties remain.

Comment: edited the answer maybe u can try this time @at.

Comment: Seems weird that WordPress would strip out style properties. Are you sure it's not a CSS specificity issue, with the display property being overridden by a more specific rule?